# How to prevent file caching in Google AppEngine?

Tags: google-app-engine, caching, google-cloud-platform

How do we stop App Engine from using caches of previously loaded files?

According to Google's documents [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/requests#Python_Responses) under "App Caching", they suggest that App Engine caches files that are loaded. They seem to suggest that it is related to the presence of their main() function. However, we removed all references to main() and find that App Engine is still using cached files.

We also tried this HTML below per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286322/preventing-page-caching-in-google-app-engine) answer, but are still getting cached results in the browser. (When we return to the home page - the tables which load JSON are not getting the new file results - they are receiving the old versions of the files.)

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
```

Here is our app.yaml

```
application: OurApp
version: 0.5
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

handlers:
- url: /scripts
  static_dir: scripts

- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```

Any suggestions for how to prevent this file load caching behavior in App Engine?

Comment: If these are static files, check that an edge cache isn't getting in the way.  Add ?x=1 or similiar to the url of the file to confirm it isn't an artifact of edge cache.  Can't see you code so we can't  are these files actually the result of a reuest handler or static handler.

Comment: Can you post your `app.yaml`?

Answer (score 4):

If the files you are trying to update are static files, such as those inside the `/stylesheets` or `/scripts` folders from your project, you should take a look at this doc for [static cache expiration](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#static_cache_expiration) for GAE projects in the standard environment for Pyhton. According to it, "files are likely to be cached by the user's browser, as well as by intermediate caching proxy servers such as Internet Service Providers". But I've found a way to flush static files cached by your app on Google Cloud.

Head to your [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/) and open your project. Under the left hamburger menu, head to Storage -> Browser. There you should find at least one Bucket: your-project-name.appspot.com. Under the Lifecycle column, click on the link with respect to your-project-name.appspot.com. Delete any existing rules, since they may conflict with the one you will create now.

Create a new rule by clicking on the 'Add rule' button. For the object conditions, choose **only** the 'Newer version' option and set it to 1. Don't forget to click on the 'Continue' button. For the action, select 'Delete' and click on the 'Continue' button. Save your new rule.

This new rule will take up to 24 hours to take effect, but at least for my project it took only a few minutes. Once it is up and running, the version of the files being served by your app under your-project-name.appspot.com **will always be the latest deployed**, solving the problem. Also, if you are routinely editing your static files, you should remove any `expiration` element from handlers related to those static files and the `default_expiration` element from the app.yaml file, which will help avoid unintended caching by other servers.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. This will save a ton of time.

Comment: Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

The section of the doc that you cite has to do with how python files on the server side are handled. It's a server-side optimization, and is *entirely* separate from how a browser caches HTML from your application.

You can specify additional HTTP headers (e.g., Cache-Control) in `app.yaml`. See the [Static File Handlers](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Static_file_handlers) section in the doc. You can also add headers dynamically via the `self.response.header`. This is discussed, with a small example, in the [Responses](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/requests#Python_Responses) section of the doc.